# Overlapping texts from Chapters and Sections in headers using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using fancyhdr for my pages and I'm having problems. The headers have titles of "sections" on the LHS and "Chapters" on the RHS. Lengthy texts in these titles make the headers overlap and look improper. I would prefer to have only Chapter titles on the header please. Any suggestions on how to do that?

This is what it looks like

[image: overlapping header texts]

This is a sample of my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\newtheorem{mytherm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.1}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.10,0.00,1.00}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                        
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    frame=none
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

If I can't get only the chapter titles on the header, then any suggestion on how to make them not overlap will do.

Thanks

Comment: Add `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}` before or after `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum This leaves just the section headings. One also needs `\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}`, it seems

Comment: And you should follow the advice in the log file and do either `\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}` or `\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}` to account for the header that takes more space than usual (probably because of the rule).